# Opposite of "ANativeWindow_fromSurface"

Tags: android, android-ndk

With the method

```
ANativeWindow* ANativeWindow_fromSurface(JNIEnv* env, jobject surface);
```

I can get ANativeWindow object.

Can I get the opposite? [jobject of surface from ANativeWindow]

(I want to use this surface in java...)

Comment: NOTE: For the Android Java "ImageReader" have the method "getSurface", but for "AImageReader" have only the function "AImageReader_getWindow". and I want to get surface from my AImageReader object.

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56601435/5052296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android API level 26, there is

```
jobject ANativeWindow_toSurface(JNIEnv *env, ANativeWindow *window)
```

> Return a Java Surface object derived from the ANativeWindow, for
> interacting with it through Java code.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/native-activity#anativewindow_tosurface